# Can't access path specified by rake routes command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, rake

I can't seem to correctly understand the routing in rails 3.1.

(keeping in mind I'm working on a project that depends on the refinery cms gem)
In my routes I have the following:

```
Blog::Application.routes.draw do

  resources :news, :as => :news_items, :controller => :news_items, :only => [:show, :index]

  scope :module => "refinery" do
    scope(:path => 'refinery', :as => 'refinery_admin', :module => 'admin') do
      resources :news, :as => :news_items, :controller => :news_items
      #resources :news, :except => :show, :as => :news_items, :controller => :news_items
    end
  end
end
```

The output of the rake routes command is:

```
news_items GET    /news(.:format)                              {:action=>"index", :controller=>"news_items"}
                              news_item GET    /news/:id(.:format)                          {:action=>"show", :controller=>"news_items"}
              refinery_admin_news_items GET    /refinery/news(.:format)                     {:action=>"index", :controller=>"refinery/admin/news_items"}
                                        POST   /refinery/news(.:format)                     {:action=>"create", :controller=>"refinery/admin/news_items"}
           new_refinery_admin_news_item GET    /refinery/news/new(.:format)                 {:action=>"new", :controller=>"refinery/admin/news_items"}
          edit_refinery_admin_news_item GET    /refinery/news/:id/edit(.:format)            {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"refinery/admin/news_items"}
               refinery_admin_news_item GET    /refinery/news/:id(.:format)                 {:action=>"show", :controller=>"refinery/admin/news_items"}
                                        PUT    /refinery/news/:id(.:format)                 {:action=>"update", :controller=>"refinery/admin/news_items"}
                                        DELETE /refinery/news/:id(.:format)                 {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"refinery/admin/news_items"}
```

The following code in my application leads to an error:

```
<%= form_for [:refinery, @news_item] do |f| %>
<% end %>
```

Telling me that the following path:

```
undefined method `refinery_news_items_path' for #<#<Class:0x0000010663c480>:0x00000106623980>
```

doesn't exist.

Any path from the rake routes command would just not work. I'm pretty confident that's it's a setting issue. I'm actually kind of writing a plugin to the RefineryCMS gem without actually using the plugin generator, I'm just building it as if it was a normal web app.

My project is hosted here for those who care to take a peak. http://github.com/mabounassif/blog

Anyone knows what might be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem was with the way the Refinery CMS gem works. Apparently I shouldn't use the url helper right away, I should use the following instead:

```
main_app.new_refinery_admin_news_item_path
```

Answer (score 0):

You're scoping your "refinery" scope as "refinery_admin" so when you did your rake routes, you got `refinery_admin_news_items`

if you take out that `:as => 'refinery_admin'` clause, your routes will return back to "normal"

Comment: Nope that's not it. I'll probably spend some time figuring out what's really going on.